# HTML5 Canvas: Calculate the Mouseposition after Zooming and Translating

Tags: html, canvas, coordinates, scale

I try to develope an interactive viewer for vector drawings and want to have the feature of zooming.
The function for zooming works pretty good but now I have the problem to calculate the mouseposition for picking objects.
The event gives back the screen coordinates. The canvas doesn't have a methode to use the transformation matrix in the inverse way.
Does anyone have a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 3):

I made a very small a simple class for keeping track of the transformation matrix.

I added an invert() function for reasons like this. I also made an invertPoint() function but didn't put it in the final version. It's not hard to deduce though, just invert and transform point together.

I often just calculate the appropraite transform with this class and then use `setTransform`, depending on the application.

I wish I could give you a more specific solution but without a code sample of what you want that'd be hard to do.

[Here's](https://github.com/simonsarris/Canvas-tutorials/blob/master/transform.js) the transformation class code. And [here's](http://simonsarris.com/blog/471-a-transformation-class-for-canvas-to-keep-track-of-the-transformation-matrix) a blog post with a bit of an explanation.

Comment: Hi Simon, thanks for your quick reply. The solution is perfect. I will try to incorporate your clean classes in my project today.<br> It is a shame that canvas hasn't got proper methods for requirements like this. Android and every other graphic platform that I know have it.

Comment: You should add an invert function that gives back a new Transformobject/Matrix. Otherwise I have to call invert a second time after I am finished with my screen to world translations. This could be more performant.

Answer (score -1):

Here are some valuable functions for your library that preserve the matrix state and needed to build up a scene graph:

```
Transform.prototype.reset = function() {
  this.m = [1,0,0,1,0,0];
  this.stack = [];
};

Transform.prototype.push = function() {
    this.stack.push(this.m.slice());
};

Transform.prototype.pop = function() {
    this.m = this.stack.pop();
};
```